# Select all rows but park on specific

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show all rows in a table but park on a specific one.

```
Select * from t_table
```

will show me all but park on the top.

```
select * from t_table where id=1000
```

will only show me id=1000.

what I need is

```
select * from t_table locate id=1000
```

is this possible ?

Example :
[image]

If the storedprocedure showing this select has a parameter @PartCode.
This can be NULL (show all) of a certain partcode. f.e. 2000443

The select in the stored procedure should park on this partcode but not filter
[image]

Comment: what do you need exactly?

Comment: *park on a specific one* I have no idea what that means

Comment: Have added example.

Comment: What you are after is behaviour in Management Studio, not SQL Server (which appears to be your RDBMS from the images). You could order your results to bring the desired row to the top, or look at [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com) which allows you to search in the results panel.

Comment: Yes Stu this is in Studio, but the SP is called from an external application, hence the wish for pointing/parking on a certain value. 
This is pure for illustration purposes. 
The resultset that is coming back to the external application needs to be like shown.
Having the asked partcode on top will work to. 
What code do I implement to get this asked for partcode to the top ?

Comment: It sounds like you need a feature request to the developers of this external application then - there is no concept of your requirement in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your required "partcode" appear at the top of the result set you will need to pass its value as a parameter to your procedure, so assuming this is `@PartCode`

```
<your select query>
order by
  case when t.Partcode = @PartCode then 0 else 1 end, <other criteria>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `top 1`

```
select top 1 * from t_table order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a case statement in an order by. It would always return your specific record as row 1 but would still order by other IDs below.

Something like the following should work:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE Partcode
      WHEN 2000443 THEN 1 --2000443 being the ID to return first.
      ELSE 2
   END, id
```

Comment: Just a note, that's a case _expression_, not statement.